# How can I access mainframe data with .Net applications and SQL Queries?

Tags: .net, sql, mainframe, adapter

We have a large amount of data stored on an IBM mainframe using VSAM files. A lot of this data is dropped on the network every night in the form of text files to be processed and dumped into FoxPro and SQL Server databases. There are also many text files produced nightly by custom applications that get uploaded to the mainframe to keep everything in sync.

Keeping the everything in sync is very tricky, to say the least. We are not getting rid of the mainframe any time soon and we would like to replace all the nightly batch processing with real time access to the mainframe data.

We would like to be able to:

1. Read data directly from the mainframe and produce reports based on it. Possibly using SQL queries.
2. Read and Write data from custom .Net applications.

We are not looking for a new platform to interface with the mainframe like [Information Builders](http://www.informationbuilders.com/products/webfocus/) offers. We don't want to build application modules or reports with new "Business Intelligence" tools. We already know how to generate reports and write custom applications using SQL,.Net, Visual Studio, etc.  All we are looking for is some sort of adapter to connect to our mainframe data.

Any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT:

Would [Microsoft's Host Integration Server](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/host-integration.aspx) allow connectivity to the mainframe? 
What is HIS meant for?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need a SQL interface to your VSAM files like maybe [Connx](http://www.connx.com/products/vsam.html) or [Attunity](http://www.attunity.com/vsam_data_access) provides.

Comment: Have you had experience with either of those options?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work for these guys and the product is simple and very effective. I have no link to the company any more. http://www.datadirect.com/products/mainframe-integration/shadow-rte/zdirect/data/index.ssp

Answer (score 1):

If you have CICS on the mainframe, you could use [CICS Web Services](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/topics/dfhws_overview.html) (SOAP) or [CICS Web Support](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.doc/dfhs3/topics/dfhs3wq.html) (REST) to access your VSAM files.  This would necessitate writing CICS application programs in [COBOL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/topics/dfhp3_cobol_intro.html), [C/C++](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/topics/develop_cplusplus.html), [PL/I](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/topics/dfhp3_pli_intro.html), [Assembler](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/topics/dfhp3_assem_intro.html), or [Java](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc/topics/dfhpjpart2.html).  It would save you from purchasing a product, which may be cost-prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of SQL to VSAM products.  IBM has their Classic Federation, Neon has one, et al...